# call a function in if statement returns nothing

Tags: bash, function

can anyone please help me with the following script why **usage** function is not returning its value when called in if statement, it returns nothing on executing the script

```
#! /bin/bash

function usage()
{
    echo "Please enter a valid process name that is currently running after the execution command"
}

if [ `echo $(ps -ef) | grep -c "$1"` -eq 0 ] then
    **usage**
elif [ `echo $(ps -ef) | grep -c "$1"` -gt 0 ] then
    Path=`ps -ef | grep "$1" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`
    echo "$Path"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first and second if/elif conditions are not being met. Therefore the script returns no value.

You can test by adding a final if statement that just echoes "No conditions met".

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply, I tried to put the final statement and nothing happens, the second condition works normally, but the first and test returns nothing.

Comment: correct answer, but you should point out that "\`echo $(ps -ef) | grep -c "$1"\`" is one painful, and apparently non-working way to search for a running process. Good luck to all.

Comment: any suggestion to search for a running process?!

Comment: `pgrep`?  Or, if you know the PID and own it, `if kill -0 $PID; then echo "The process is still running"; fi`